# What is the origin of the term "In Spades"?

Tags: etymology

Near as I can tell, this phrase seems to be based on the idea that the suit of spades is of higher value than any other card - which I believe is only true in the card game "[Spades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spades)".

Is this card game the origin of the phrase?  If so, when did it become a popular phrase to describe what it means today?

Comment: That's what OED has too, although it's an entry which is awaiting an update and marks the expression "chiefly US". The earliest citation is 1929. I had thought that (since the expression means "in abundance" even according to OED), it meant *in spadefuls* or *by the spadeful,* referring to the garden implement, but then I don't play bridge.

Comment: I was hoping for a more historic analysis of the term...but I guess a simple "it's from Bridge" is what I'll settle for.

Comment: @Andrew: That interpretation never occurred to me (but then I *do* play bridge! :) There are other card games where spades is considered the "highest" suit - which I've always considered is not unconnected to the fact that the "suit symbol" on the *ace of **spades*** is invariably more ornate/bigger than the ones on the other three aces.